# OCaml - GADT mapping

Tags: ocaml

I'm struggling with understanding some aspects of using GADTs in OCaml. Let me try and talk you through my example and my understanding ...

I'm trying to implement Simon Peyton-Jones' classic paper on Combinatorial Contracts (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2000/09/pj-eber.pdf)

I want to be able to manipulate an Observable, defined as a function from a date to a value of some type (realistically a `float` or a `bool`). So, using GADTs I define a function type and an Observation type

```
type _ value = 
| Float : float -> float value
| Bool : bool -> bool value

type _ obs = Observation : (date -> 'v value) -> (date -> 'v) obs
```

What I think I am defining is that

- a `value` is either a `float` or a `bool` (built using the `Float` or `Bool` constructors, and
- an `obs` is a function from a `date` to one of the `value` types, so either a `date -> float` or a `date -> bool`

Now I define an expression, which enables me to combine Observables

```
type _ expr =
| Konst : 'v value -> 'v expr
| Obs : 'v obs -> 'v expr
| Lift : ('v1 -> 'v2) * 'v1 expr -> 'v2 expr
```

So far so good. An expression is either a constant, an observation (which is  either a `date->float` or `date->bool`), or a function applied to an expression.

Now I want to be able to evaluate an Observable. In reality, an Observable is built on a random process, so I have a `Distribution` module (Note that in the original paper the idea is to separate out the concept of an Observable, from it's implementation - so we could implement through lattices, monte carlo, or whatever approach we want).

```
module type Distribution_intf =
  sig
    type element = Element of float * float
    type t = element list

    val lift : t -> f:(float -> float) -> t
    val expected : t -> float
  end
```

so, given a `compose` function 
    let compose f g = fun x -> f (g x)

I should be able to think about the evaluation of an `Observable`. Here is a mapping function (I've taken out the Boolean case for clarity)

```
type rv = date -> Distribution.t

let rec observable_to_rv : type o. o Observable.expr -> rv = 
  let open Distribution in
  function
  | Konst (Float f) -> fun (_:date) -> [Element(1.0, f)]
  | Lift (f,obs) -> compose (lift ~f) (observable_to_rv o) (*ERROR HERE *)
```

Now things get problematic. When I try and compile, I get the following error message (on the Lift pattern match):

```
Error: This expression has type v1#0 -> o
   but an expression was expected of type float -> float
   Type v1#0 is not compatible with type float
```

I don't understand why: A `Lift` expression has type

```
Lift: ('v1 -> 'v2) * 'v1 expr -> 'v2 expr
```

So given a `Lift(f,o)`, then shouldn't the compiler constrain that since `observable_to_rv` has type `date -> float`, then `'v2` must be a `float`, and since `lift` has type `float -> float` then `'v1` must be a float, so Lift should be defined on any tuple of type `(float -> float, float expr)`.

What am I missing ?

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the type variable `'v1` in Lift is existentially quantified:

```
Lift: ('v1 -> 'v2) * 'v1 expr -> 'v2 expr
```

means

```
Lift: ∃'v1. ('v1 -> 'v2) * 'v1 expr -> 'v2 expr
```

In other words, given a value `Lift(f,x): 'b expr` the only information that the type checker has is that there is a type `'a` such that `f:'a -> 'b` and `x:'a expr`, nothing more.

In particular going back to your error message (with a somewhat recent version of compiler(≥ 4.03)):

> Type $Lift_'v1 is not compatible with type float

it is not possible to unify this existential type introduced by the Lift constructor to the float type, or any concrete type, because there no information left in the type system on the actual concrete type hidden behind `'v1` at this point.

EDIT:
The essence of your problem is that you are trying to build a float random variable from a chain of expression `'a expr` which can contain intermediary expressions of any type and just need to result with `'a` expression. Since you can neither express the condition `only float sub-expression` in the type system nor construct non-float random variable with your current design, this spells trouble.

The solution is either to remove the ability to build non-float expression or to add the ability to handle non-float random variables .Taking the second option would look like

```
module Distribution:
  sig
    type 'a element = {probability:float; value: 'a}
    type 'a t = 'a element list

    val lift : 'a t -> f:('a -> 'b) -> 'b t
    val expected : float t -> float
  end = struct … end
```

Then your observable_to_rv random variable typed as `'a expr -> 'a rv` will type-check.

Comment: OK, but surely the point of a generic type `'a` is that I can map a concrete type such as a `float`onto it (isn't it?).

What approach would you suggest to solving the underlying problem?

Comment: The point of an existentially quantified type variable `'a` is exactly to remove the ability to map it to a specific type. You need to either remove this variable, or extends the definition of your distribution and random variable to be able to handle any type as I have explained in my edit.